# Data sharing across processes

Tags: windows, data, process

I have a C# .NET app that downloads a users Tweets using LinqToTwitter. This is for TV broadcast - the client wants to show Tweets on air. We have two other apps that need to access these tweets. One is a C++ app and one will use MS Script Host. These two apps don't run at the same time - it's one or the other.

My question is, of the many ways to share this data, which would you choose?

**DataBase** - Like MySql. This was my first choice. But then it seemed like overkill for the 10-20 tweets they would get per day.

**Streaming** - Like TCP or named pipes. This would involve some type of protocol. Like "Give me the last 10 tweets..."

**Xml** - Store the data in a file all programs can access. Simplest, but just doesn't feel right for some reason.

**Memory Mapped IO** - I think this would require a COM library for the scripts to be able to use it

There are others. Just curious what you would use. I am the only programmer in a small company and don't have others to bounce ideas off of.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for shared storage, another option might be Redis (in-memory store with client/server protocol).  If you decide to stream, might want to consider 0mq instead of straight up TCP. Or possibly even something like RabbitMQ

Comment: Redis looks cool. Too bad it's not too Windows native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vote for a database. Any concerns around locking, concurrent access, persistence etc would be dealt with by the database, and more clients can be added without impacting the others. The architecture would then be;

```
                              +--> Reader A
                              |
Data Extractor --> Database --+--> Reader B
                              |
                              +--> Reader C
```

It would also be straightforward to run reports on the tweets later e.g. stats per day.

Comment: Thanks for the input. DB was my first as the most robust.

Answer (score 1):

A database would work well. If you are concerned about deploying the database, or licensing, you might want to look at something built into the operating system, such as MSMQ (called Message Queuing in the latest documentation), or the built in database, ESENT:

- [Managed ESENT](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126043422/http://managedesent.codeplex.com:80/) stand alone library
- As built into Windows 8.1: [Blog entry with link to MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/martinc/managedesent-is-in-windows-8-1-and-on-msdn)

Comment: Thanks. I am unfamiliar with ESENT and am researching it now.